# Why does 'Do you want to allow this app to make changes to device come up on Windows'

Tags: java, windows

I'm a developer and I'm suddenly finding on Windows 10 that after installing the latest version of my application into C:/Program Files every time I start it I get the following popup. I think this must be a Windows change rather than anything in my application but I dont understand why it is now occurring.

I wouldn't mind it coming up on initial install but it comes up every time I run it, it only comes up if installed into the (default) location

The application is Java based within an exe wrapper, the application is signed with a valid certificate from Comodo.

[image: Authorisation <Message coming up]

Done some further tests

I have a 64bit installer that puts in C:/Program Files/Jthink/Songkong, once installed I can either run SongKong64.exe or SOngKong64.bat

Then I have a 32bit installer that puts in C:/Program Files(x86)/Jthink/Songkong, once installed  I can either run SOngKong.exe or SongKong.bat

- If I install 64bit installer into C:/Program Files(x86) it works okay
- If I install 32bit installer into C:/Program Files it works okay
- SongKong64.bat always works where-ever installed
- If I simply rename Songkong64.exe (and Songkong64.ini) to Songkong.bat and Songkong.ini it then works okay

**The only problem is Songkong64.exe when installed into subdirectory of C:/Program Files, why would that be ?**

Comment: Are you writing anything in the program directory when your program executes?

Comment: No I don't think so

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc ive done some other installs and the problem seems specific to using an exe with 64 in the name within C:/Program Files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a a silly mistake made my myself, the *Run as Administrator* tick box was checked for this particular exe, and this is what causes the dialog to come up. Subsequent reinstalls into the same folder did not reset this flag but if I deleted the folder and did a fresh install it then worked as expected without the dialog appearing (Run as Adminstrator was no longer checked)